# Is there any possibility to send a mail in sharepoint 2010 using gmail smtp configuration

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Is there any possibility  to send a  mail in sharepoint 2010  using gmail smtp configuration.

I tried using .net.It is successfully going.. But i need this in sharepoint 2010 without usind SMTP configuration in Central administration in sharepoint 2010

I tried it by using event handler, but i can't

thanks in advance.....

```
            //SmtpClient serverobj = new SmtpClient();
            //serverobj.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //serverobj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "Password");
            //serverobj.Port = 587;
            //serverobj.Host = "Smtp.gmail.com";
            //serverobj.EnableSsl = true;
            //MailMessage msgobj = new MailMessage();
            //msgobj.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", Subject ", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            //msgobj.To.Add("yyy@gmail.com.com");
            //msgobj.Subject = "New Application Request";
            //msgobj.Body = "Hi this is test mail";
            //serverobj.Send(msgobj);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you mean by using .Net successfully? and unsuccessfully in event handler?  The CA will contain configuration settings that you can retrieve using SP Server API, you would still use System.Net.* API to generate an email message and sending it.

Comment: @Roman i need to send the mail to admin after adding the new item in the list.. I need to configure the outgoing mail bound , from email address etc..through code only(without touching the Sharepoint CA manually)

Comment: Can you share your code for the item changed event handler?  Are you sure it's firing?  The actual mail sending logic should be straight forward

Comment: @ Romam plz check the  updated post for mail sending code

Comment: What is the error message do you get when you attempt this? are you able to debug the exception generated?

Comment: @roman. No error. I put break point and check the code. the code excuting without any error, but mail is not going

Comment: tested your code in .net client and it does work (make sure that no firewall blocking is set up, although you'd get a host unreachable .Net exception).  I am recreating your example in SP vm.

Comment: @Roman Thanku so much. Let me know once after your completion

Comment: Interesting. My test in the VM yields weird results. In the console 3.5 app, i can run that code just fine.  In the item receiver context, i am getting AuthenticationException, remote server has invalid certificate error. It may have to do with NAT config on my VM but overall i can see that the code is making a connection. I would suggest for you to attempt to use Fiddler to see if code is making the request.

Comment: @Ramon did u get any solution to my problem. Thanks for afforting me

Comment: I am seeing that the request is coming from within Event Receiver to the smtp.google.com, so your issue must be environmental. When you execute the code, can you use fiddler to inspect the traffic?